# Is it a good idea to train BatchNorm layer with running stats?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

As far as I know, `BatchNorm` will use batch stats in `train` mode, but use running stats (`running_mean`/`running_var`) in `eval` mode. How about just always use running stats in both `train` and `eval` mode?

In my opinion, we use `eval` mode in inference phase after all. why don't we use `eval` style `BatchNorm` from the beginning in the training phase?

Answer (score -1):

From https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html?highlight=batchnorm2d#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d

> [...] during training this layer keeps running estimates of its computed mean and variance, which are then used for normalization during evaluation.

I imagine if you never set BatchNorm to train, then no values (or some default values) are stored and the layer will not be optimized for your data. It is similar to linear/conv layers. "Why don't we set them to eval in the training phase?" Well because we want the layers to learn something that we can use in evaluation mode.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make my question clear. As far as I know, `BatchNorm` will use batch stats in `train` mode, but use running stats in `eval` mode. How about just always use `running_mean`/`running_var` in both `train` and `eval` mode?